# Spring Azure AD - Get user's ADDRESS after authentication

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, active-directory

I'm using the sample provided by Microsoft, I authenticate myself just fine. I retrieve basic info about my user after authenticating. How do I retrieve more info about my user (e.g. **street number, house number, phone number etc.**)?

1. I'm using this Azure AD Spring Boot Backend Sample - [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-backend-sample)
2. I start & login (https://localhost:8080)
3. Authentication success!
4. I get basic info about the user (*e.g. Name, Surname*)
5. How do I get **more info** about the user (*e.g. Street Number, House Number, Phone Number*)?

Code (HomeController.java):

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken auth) {
    final OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = this.authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
            auth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
            auth.getName());

    // Name, Surname
    model.addAttribute("userName", auth.getName());
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Welcome, "+auth.getName());
    // Azure info
    model.addAttribute("clientName", client.getClientRegistration().getClientName());

    // HERE I WANT TO SEND A (MICROSOFT OR AD) GRAPH API REQUEST TO GET 
    // THIS USER'S ADDRESS (street number, house number, etc.)

    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, you could mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is that we need to get the access token from auth.

We could get access token with following code.

```
DefaultOidcUser user = (DefaultOidcUser)auth.getPrincipal();
String accessToken = user.getIdToken().getTokenValue();
```

How to send the request API with Java code, please have a try it with following code.

[Azure AD graph REST API for get a user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsers)

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version=1.6
```

[Microsoft graph Rest API for get a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}?$select=displayName,givenName,postalCode,...
```

> **Note:** If you need a different property set, you can use the OData $select query parameter. For example, to return displayName, givenName, and postalCode, you would use the add the following to your query $select=displayName,givenName,postalCode

Follow is the demo code:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

 String url = "https://graph.windows.net/{yourtenantId}/users/{userObjectId}?api-version=1.6"; //take Azure AD graph for example.
 HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
 HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
 request.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+ accessToken);
 HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 // Read the contents of an entity and return it as a String.
 String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
 JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(content);
```